# Couldn't find [model] without an ID - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have multiples forms in the Edit view like you can see below:

View

```
-@posts.each do |post|
  .form
    = simple_form_for post, url: update_posts_path do |f|
      = f.input :title
      = f.submit
```

Then when I'm updating any form I get this error 'Couldn't find Pots without an ID'. You can see the controller and the routes file here:

Controller

```
def update
  @post = Posts.find(params[:id]) //If I change it for Posts.first then is working
  if @post.update_attributes(params.require(:posts).permit(:title))
    redirect_to ....
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Sorry."
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Routes File

```
resources :posts, :only => [:index, :edit, :update] do
  get "edit", :on => :collection, :as => :edit
  patch "update", :on => :collection, :as => :update
end
```

I think that the error is that for some reason this (@post = Posts.find(params[:id])) is returning a nil object then the controller can't update it. Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Are you sure about your model being `Posts` with an `s` at the end ?

Comment: Thanks, it was and error, now is in singular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is the `:on => :collection` part. This allows the action to be called without an id, so `params[:id]` is empty.

`:on => :collection` is normally used for index like actions that have a set of records as a result, so don't need the id part.

btw: the whole thing:

```
get "edit", :on => :collection, :as => :edit
patch "update", :on => :collection, :as => :update
```

is redundant, the first line:

```
resources :posts, :only => [:index, :edit, :update]
```

tells Rails everything it needs.

Answer (score 0):

For update action you are using `:on => :collection` but your request is put/patch request so you will use `patch "update", :on => :member, :as => :update` also make changes in form_for as per your route.Use`<%=simple_form_for post ,:url=> update_post_path(post) do |f| %>` instead of `url: update_posts_path`

Regarding `params.require(:posts).permit(:title)`

1. First problem : you are using `posts` instead of `post`
2. second is Parameter `:id` is missing

you will use `params.require(:post).permit(:title,:id)` instead of `params.require(:posts).permit(:title)`